# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: vb.net

I have created a program, which works fine in debug. However, when I compile the program and install it, open it etc, I get the following:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AutoUpdater.NET, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Has anyone had experience in this and how to resolve it? I have searched Google etc and can not find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/01/09/how-to-resolve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-issues-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't resolve it. Copy Local is set to true. The application is build on .NET Framework 4 Client.

Comment: You need to copy the `.dll` file to the executable path.

Comment: I have copied the DLL to bin/debug Have also tried it in Publish

Comment: Are you using click-once deployment?

Comment: No not using Click Once. Never do.

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: I am using Inno Setup for the installation, which works fine.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue. It appears that when I try to sign a key, an error displays saying that AutoUpdater.NET does not have a Strong Name. When I go to the Reference and click on AutoUpdater.Net, the option to activate Strong Name in the property window is disabled. Any ideas?